# Cannot convert object as strings to int - Unable to parse string

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, data-cleaning

I have a data frame with one column denoting range of Ages. The data type of the Age column in shown as string. I am trying to convert string values to numeric for the model to interpret the features.

[image]

I tried the following to convert to 'int'.

```
df.Age = pd.to_numeric(df.Age)
```

**I get the following error:**

```
ValueError: Unable to parse string "0-17" at position 0
```

I also tried using the 'errors = coerce' parameter but it gave me a different error:

```
df.Age = pd.to_numeric(df.Age, errors='coerce').astype(int)
```

**Error:**

```
ValueError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer
```

But there are no NA values in any column in my df

Comment: it is because `NaN` is a float, which cannot be casted to int, you can fill them with 0 and try again

Comment: Actually data instead of images, would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

`Age` seems to be a [categorical variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categorical_variable), so you should treat it as such. `pandas` has a neat [`category`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/categorical.html)  dtype which converts your labels to integers under the hood:

```py
df['Age'] = df['Age'].astype('category')
```

Then you can access the underlying integers usin the `cat` accessor method

```py
codes = df['Age'].cat.codes # This returns integers
```

Also you probably want to make `Age` an ordered categorical variable, for which you can also find a neat recipe in [the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/categorical.html#controlling-behavior).

```py
from pandas.api.types import CategoricalDtype

age_category = CategoricalDtype([...your labels in order...], ordered=True)

df['Age'] = df['Age'].astype(age_category)
```

Then you can acces the underlying codes in the same way and be sure that they will reflect the order you entered for your labels.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, I would say it is because you are attempting to convert a string that has not only an int in it. Your string is "0-17", which is not an integer. If it had been "17" or "0", the conversion would have worked.

```
    val = int("0")
    val = int("17")
```

I have no idea what your to_numeric method is, so I am not sure if I am answering your question.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you [`split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html)

```
a=df["age"].str.split("-", n=2, expand=True)
df['age_from']=a[0].to_frame()
df['age_to']=a[1].to_frame()
```

Here is what I got at the end!

```
         date    age
0  2018-04-15  12-20
1  2018-04-15   2-30
2  2018-04-18  5-46+
         date    age age_from age_to
0  2018-04-15  12-20       12     20
1  2018-04-15   2-30        2     30
2  2018-04-18  5-46+        5    46+
```